# How to add extra security to Firebase Realtime Database read securities?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my mobile app connected to Firebase realtime database with read access to everyone (read = true).
Will this be a problem in the future since you pay for what you use and users can do a lot of searches in there?
What can I do to protect this from happening and not go over "the budget"?

Thanks!

Comment: Before the billing part, are you users supposed to read the whole database (which doesn't sound secure as there'll be other users' data)? You should use [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to restrict access and allow users to read data that they are supposed to. That itself should reduce some costs as people cannot download the whole database. If you need help with a specific security rule, then it'll be best to share a screenshot of your database and explain what kind of rules you need.

Comment: @Dharmaraj. Since it's a simple database I want the users (everyone) to read all data (while the authentication is not set). But, for example, a user can request data multiple times and that will abuse the database. What can I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules determine who has read and write access to your database, how your data is structured, and what indexes exist. These rules live on the Firebase servers and are enforced automatically at all times. Every read and write request will only be completed if your rules allow it. By default, your rules do not allow anyone access to your database. This is to protect your database from abuse until you have time to customize your rules or set up authentication.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Since it's a simple database I want the users (everyone) to read all data (while the authentication is not set). But, for example, a user can request data multiple times and that will abuse the database. What can I do to prevent that?